# Accessing properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
module MyModule {
    class MyClass {
        someTest = 'Hello';
        options = {
            myNumber: 3,
            myObject: {
                MyOtherObject: {
                    myOtherNumber1: myNumber,   // Error
                    myOtherNumber2: options.myNumber,   //Error         
                    myOtherText: someText    // Error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reference myNumber from myOtherNumber1 or my OtherNumber2 or someText from myOtherText??

With myOtherNumber1 'cannot find 'myNumber'.

With myOtherNumber2 'cannot find 'options'.

With myOtherText: 'cannot find someText'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are instance properties that must be accessed using the `this` keyword i.e.

`this.options.myNumber`

`this.someText`

Since nothing is indicated, these properties are `public` by default and may be accessed outside the class.

Comment: I realize this but I think my problem was that it was late at night AND there were a few other factors going on in my dev environment. Marked as answer though.